# Include java libraries into own library

Tags: ant, java

I created a little framework for myself which I want to use in multiple projects. I also want the distributed jar-file to include all external libraries so that my projects just need to include my library to access all external libraries.

I need this to simplify updating the external libraries.

So I placed this in my build.xml which adds all libraries from dist/lib into my own jar-file.

```
<target name="-post-jar">  
    <!-- Include all java libraries -->
    <fileset dir="dist/lib" id="extern.libs">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>

    <!-- Add the libraries from the fileset to the project.jar -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist.jar}" update="true">  
        <zipgroupfileset refid="extern.libs"/>
    </jar>  
</target>
```

But when I try to use external libraries like "org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component" I get the error that this library could not be found.

Is there a better way to include the external libraries into my own library so that my project can use them?

Comment: Use external dependency management tool like Maven.

Answer (score 2):

You can publish a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) artifact, which users of your framework can then use without having to include the dependencies yourself--your pom is enough.

If you want to create an "all-in-one" artifact, consider something like [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) or [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) or Maven's [Shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to create a jar that has no external dependencies.

Comment: I think using maven would be overkill for my needs. I'm trying out OneJar at the moment but I couln't get it to work until now...

Answer (score 1):

The standard classloader can't find class files inside a jar that is itself inside a jar. You must add every jar to the classpath, and not nest jars.

BTW, it would probably be a bad idea to allow nesting jars: you would end up with 6 or seven versions of commons-lang or log4j into every project, because many libraries depend on them.

Comment: That is a good point and I have to think about it. I just want to be able to add one library to my projects and this library should drag in all the dependancies.

Comment: That's what Maven (and Ivy) are all about: managing dependencies. I personally find it often harder to use Maven than to handle the dependencies myself, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [One-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) or [Fat Jar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/).
If you use maven you can use maven-assembly plugin.

Comment: I'm currently trying OneJar, Fat Jar seems to be an Eclipse Plugin but I use NetBeans ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on IDE...If you are using Eclipse then it is very easy...go to Properties->Build Path and then add library...

Comment: I use NetBeans and there is a similar property for adding libraries but I want my projects to be able to access all libraries that are included in my own library project.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about including the dependent libraries in the built jar.  Adding jars to the build path in the IDE will not automatically include them built jar.

Comment: Yes that is the point. But I want to be able to access the libraries in my project too.